# Get max value of x field only from objects satisfying 'true' for y field

Tags: c#, linq

Say I've got a database of Person objects with the following fields:

```
class Person
{
     public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
     public string CountryOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use a query (LINQ or some other C# code) that searches the `birthDate`s of `Person`s born only in (e.g.) USA, and returns the `Person` with the max `birthDate`. If there are more than one `Person`s born on this date, it should return all of them.

What is the way to do it?

Comment: As an aside, I'd *strongly* recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions for properties.

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it sounds like you want to:

- Filter by country
- Group by birth date
- Order the groups in descending order
- Take the first group

So (assuming the property names have been fixed to follow conventions):

```
var query = db.People
              .Where(p => p.CountryOfBirth == "USA")
              .GroupBy(p => p.BirthDate)
              .OrderByDescending(p => p.Key)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return `null` if there are no groups because there are no people born in the USA. To return an empty sequence instead, you could flatten the first result if there is one:

```
var query = db.People
              .Where(p => p.CountryOfBirth == "USA")
              .GroupBy(p => p.BirthDate)
              .OrderByDescending(p => p.Key)
              .Take(1)
              .SelectMany(p => p);
```

Comment: Since this is set returning query, wouldn't `Take(1).SelectMany(g => g)` be more appropriate than `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: @IvanStoev: Do you mean so that it returns an empty set instead? Sure, that would work. Will update with that option.

Answer (score 2):

I know how to do it in 2 queries if that helps.
Have a look on this:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/c3BNWp

Code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Person>(){
            new Person(){
                Name = "1",
                countryOfBirth = "USA",
                birthDate = new DateTime(2000,1,1)
            },
                new Person(){
                Name = "2",
                countryOfBirth = "USA",
                birthDate = new DateTime(1999,1,1)
            },
                new Person(){
                Name = "3",
                countryOfBirth = "USA",
                birthDate = new DateTime(2000,1,1)
            },
                new Person(){
                Name = "4",
                countryOfBirth = "Other",
                birthDate = new DateTime(2000,1,1)
            },
                new Person(){
                Name = "5",
                countryOfBirth = "SomeOther",
                birthDate = new DateTime(2000,1,1)
            }
        };
        var max = list.Where(p=> p.countryOfBirth == "USA").Max(a=> a.birthDate);
        Console.WriteLine(max);
        var maxList = list.Where(p=> p.countryOfBirth == "USA" && p.birthDate == max).ToList();
        foreach(var p in maxList){
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
     public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }
     public string countryOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```